# iphone / ios App with background audio session stops user from answering incoming call

Tags: ios, audio, background, call, avplayer

I have an iPhone app (5.1 SDK) which plays audio in the background. Many times when there is an incoming call, the incoming call is displayed but the user cannot slide the slider to answer it and the call is missed.

I am using - (void)beginInterruption to pause all audio when an incoming call arrives but it doesn't seem to stop this issue from occurring.

Has anyone ever encountered this before?

Comment: Is your beginInterruption code being called? If so, is the music actually stopping? Are you streaming audio over the network or local files? What player are you using?

Comment: It appears the my beginInterruption was not being called correctly since upgrading my ios to 5.1.1 .. strange. I have since rewrote the code that sets the AVPlayerDelegate and the interruptions calls are now being called. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wanna mark this as the answer since it was indeed your problem I'll repost my comment.

Is your beginInterruption code being called? If so, is the music actually stopping? Are you streaming audio over the network or local files? What player are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) beginInterruption {

    if (playing) {

        playing = NO;

        interruptedWhilePlaying = YES;

        [self updateUserInterface];

    }

}



NSError *activationError = nil;

- (void) endInterruption {

    if (interruptedWhilePlaying) {

        BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];

        if (!success) { /* handle the error in activationError */ }

        [player play];

        playing = YES;

        interruptedWhilePlaying = NO;

        [self updateUserInterface];

    }

}
```